# Is it possible to match string with database entry and get result where a part of string get matched?

Tags: php, mysql, search, string-matching

Actually I am saving my user's number i:e

> +92 3123456789

in database without their country code i:e

> 3123456789

But the problem is that user can have saved the same number in his contact book but may be with country code i:e

> +92 3123456789

or with local code i:e

> 03123456789

So, whenever i have to search for that number i have search for `03123456789` or may be `+92 3123456789` from database record which is saved without country or local codes i:e `3123456789`.

So, please help me get out of this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Please help me get out of this problem as soon as possible. I am looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: If all phone numbers from your database have the same length then you can simply cut the same amount of digits from the end of the number entered by user (`RIGHT(p_number, 10)`) and use it in your searching.

Comment: You cant do it. if the customer has stored the local code. this code can be the same in every country for different customers.

Comment: You might want to search for a phone number library that has formatting and extracting options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all who assist me in this problem. But i have found the solution on my own by running simple query which mysql function `CONCAT` i:e

> select * from `users` where '03123456789'
> LIKE CONCAT('%', phone, '%')

and for bulk contacts array search

> select * from `users` where '03123456789'
> LIKE CONCAT('%', phone, '%') OR '+923123456789'
> LIKE CONCAT('%', phone, '%')